# Cradlepoint wifi as wan with 2 networks

Tags: wan

So, basically, I currently have a cradlepoint router set up to relay a cell phone that we have jailbroken and set up to tether. That works fine.

What I would like to do, is introduce a 2nd internet source from my work mifi and have the cradlepoint prioritize the mifi, when it is available, then fail over to the tethered connection if the mifi is not available.

I have both networks added, and the mifi as #1, but it will never connect to the mifi... any ideas?

It is a cradlepoint mbr95 and is used at my home (we have 4g coverage, but no land line service). Max connections would be 10 or so, obviously not all heavily using the connection at the same time.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/t66Fd.png